# 404 and 401 errors when using Firebase Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've recently set up a CRA project and have enabled Firebase Messaging, using the latest documentation.  I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P51dI2y7QHA) particularly helpful.

- Users opt-in to notifications and get a registration token, which is stored in a db for future reference.  These are removed from the db if/when they fail.
- Messages are sent, using Cloud Functions (Node.js) with the Admin SDK.

Messages are sent by executing this in a cloud function:

```
const response = await admin.messaging().sendEach(messages);
```

I am using `sendEach` to support when a user may have multiple devices.

Everything works swimmingly for a while.

After a while (about 30 minutes or so), I start seeing these in the console when attempting to invoke the aforementioned `sendEach` method (PROJECT_ID and TOKEN are placeholders for actual values):

```
DELETE https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/registrations/<TOKEN> 404 (Not Found)        
    
POST https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/registrations 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Clearly the registration token has somehow "gone bad".  It looks like Firebase is attempting to delete the bad token (and perhaps even fix it), but it's not working.

Getting a new token with `getToken(messaging, {vapidKey: key})` does not help here.

I can clear the app data and reset the permissions for the app to get things working, but I do not expect users to be doing that.

I've found that I can remove the token from the indexedDb and then get a new token, and that fixes things.

`firebase-messaging-database`/`firebase-messaging-store` is where the token is stored.

But that would require the user to disable and re-enable messaging in the app, which I've made possible in the UI, and I don't think that's a good UX.

I would try to automate a workaround, but it seems like this is something that should "just work".  I could very well be mistaken in thinking that.

So my questions are:

1. What is causing the registration token to "go bad"?
2. How can I prevent this, or is there a known, proven workaround?
3. Why is Firebase struggling to delete and/or fix an item from its own indexedDb store?
4. What am I doing wrong? There is a high probability that this is the case.